# Linear Least-Squares Regression for Matlab

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression, regression-analysis

[image]

I am having trouble understanding this problem. I was thinking that the heart rates have something to do with the $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, but I'm not really sure how these play a role in the problem. Also, I do not understand how to do the least squares with the cosine function in the error term. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In part i, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are given; i.e. $145\times 2 \pi /60$ and $55 \times 2 \pi/60$.

Comment: For setting up the matrices for least squares, do you do the partial derivatives with the cosines in the equation? If its linear are you supposed to simplify that functions to something else?

Comment: I know you have to convert this to exponentials, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Please [don't post pages as images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305) as they are *not* SEO-friendly.